# How to know which devices are connected to my network (using C#)?

Tags: c#, mysql, networking, wireless

What I'm trying to do is insert some data on a MySQL database (like MAC address) when a user connects to my wireless network. In order to do this, I've been doing tests with my iPhone and with the "arp -a" cmd and I noticed that the result table doesn't refresh until I ping my iPhone's IP address. For example, I connect my iPhone to my wireless network and sometimes I can see the iPhone IP almost instantly on the result from "arp -a", but when I disconnect from the network the iPhone IP is still showing on the result. What can I do to avoid this? Do I have to ping a huge range of IP numbers if I want to do this for many mobile devices?

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: I think the ARP table holds the reference to the MAC/IP pair of a device that got disconnected for a while, so that if the device reconnects after a short time it gets the same IP back. I think you answered your own question there.

Comment: @Renan, thanks for your answer, ARP sometimes takes a very long time to update. For example, when I connect my iPhone to the network I have to ping my iPhone IP number and then run "arp -a", if I don't ping it takes some time to recognize the iPhone IP number; same thing when I disconnect, I need to ping the IP address and then run "arp -a" to show the updated information. I would like to know if there's a way to keep this updated, maybe not "real time" but every 1 - 5 minutes using C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to insert into a SQL table on connection and have a dd-wrt/open-wrt router you could just write a simple script on the router to submit the SQL query on client connection or disconnect.

If you do not have a dd-wrt/open-wrt capable router this quickly becomes much more difficult. Arp is a good way of detecting connections but does not detect disconnects. You could run a periodic ping against all of the known connected devices to determine disconnects. Either way, you can't directly do it in C#.

Comment: is there any good way to ping an IP range (maybe other than using for + ping)? I think I'm gonna do that to keep the "ARP -A" table updated, does that takes a lot of resources?

Comment: This might help. [http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/188286/Ping-many-devices-simultaneously](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/188286/Ping-many-devices-simultaneously)
One of the System.Net.NetworkInformation.SendAsync methods will really allow you to save time if you want to ping several IPs at the same time. The only alternative I see would be creating the same number of threads (preferably using the thread pool or BackgroundWorker) and pinging synchronously each separate IP in each separate thread.

Comment: thank you, it works really well, now I'm having another problem, I'm having huge ms numbers when I ping my iPhone, but I found this solution: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=477141. When my phone gets blocked (when the screen goes black after not using it for a while) I think that I cannot ping the iPhone anymore, do you know anything about it? Thank you for your useful answers.